# QML SystemTrayIcon multiple message icon

Tags: qt, qml

I want to set icon for message, I think the doc it's not clear for MessageIcon
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qt-labs-platform-systemtrayicon.html#showMessage-method

It's possible set another icon for message?
It's also can set different icon for different situation?
Maybe use fire icon when device overheating, or use ice icon when device temperature too low.

Comment: what does your _another icon_ mean? please clarify the question.

Comment: Hi, it's mean maybe use fire icon when device overheating, or use ice icon when device temperature too low.

Comment: There is an [icon.source](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qt-labs-platform-systemtrayicon.html#icon.source-prop) property so you can set any icon you want. Just check the [examples](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qt-labs-platform-systemtrayicon.html#details)

Comment: But icon.source also changed the tray icon, I want tray icon follow app. And custom message icon.